# Reading bytecode from an AnnotationProcessor

Tags: java, annotations, instrumentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plugging in to Java compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340353/plugging-in-to-java-compilers)

**Edit** - this appears to be a dupe of [Plugging in to Java compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340353/plugging-in-to-java-compilers)

---

I would like to implement an `AnnotationProcessor` for use with the `apt` tool that will be invoked *after* compiling a class to bytecode, that can read and modify the bytecode.

The reason for doing this is that I want to translate annotated methods to another language and replace the java methods with stubs that invoke the translated versions.

However the `AnnotationProcessorEnvironment` interface only provides methods to generate new classes, not to read back a class file that was generated in a previous round.

The instrumentation API does something similar to what I want, but only at run-time.  I am looking for a way to do this at compile time.

Comment: Closing upon request.  Not deleting since the title is descriptive and will lead more people to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Related: [Plugging in to Java compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340353/plugging-in-to-java-compilers)

I had a look when I wanted to do some manipulation in the compiler, but ended up using a post-processor.

You can manipulate the abstract syntax tree (AST) using the APT, but only with compiler-specific hacks. If you want a sample of how that's done, [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) does it with the Sun `javac` and Eclipse compilers. At present, there doesn't seem to be a better method.

Comment: Not just related, but a dupe.  Thanks for the link.